# Xcode 4.6 if statement with &&

Tags: xcode, if-statement

My problem is

```
-(IBAction)setAction:(id)sender{

    if ([labelOne.text isEqual: @"One"] && [labelTwo.text isEqual: @"Two"]) {
        labelShow.text = @"Yes it works :)";
    }   
}
```

And if i build it. It show me the error code: Thread 1: signal SIGBART

but it works if i do it like this

```
-(IBAction)setAction:(id)sender{

    if ([labelOne.text isEqual: @"One"]) {
        labelShow.text = @"Yes it works :)";
    }   
}
```

What can I do, that the First one works?:)

Answer (score 0):

The SIBABRT implies that either labelTwo or labelTwo.text is pointing to bad memory.

First figure out which pointer is bad, and then debug to see why. Also, provide a crash log when possible. There should be an error message associated in your debug output pane.

Check out [this debugging tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1).